AD keep changing key layout of the users that connect to the domain
Server : Windows Server 2019
Client : Windows 10
When I'm joining a computer to my AD and connect a user to the AD. When the session has started the keyboard of the user change to match the AD keyboard, I want it to remain as it was before joining the domain.
The problem doesn't occur for the session login page, only when a client logged in.
I've try several things :

Modify HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload with the keyboard layout that I need (It works for the loggin page but note for the current user)
I've try to change 2 GPO on the user configuration.User Configuration - Administrative Template - Regional and Language Options

Restrict selection of Windows menu and dialogs language - Disable
Restrict the UI languages Windows menus and dialogs language - Disable


I've try to change the "local" gpo un the computer configuration. Computer Configuration - Administrative Template - System - Local services

Disallow copying of user input methods to the system accordance - Enable



It doesn't change anything. The keyboard still stay the AD's keyboard layout.
I wanna use a GPO to fix this.
To be noted : I've several keyboards layout possible depending on the machine, so a fix keyboard layout is not a solution.
